# Declaring a long string using + in java

Tags: java, string, performance

What is the best practice to declaring a long string in java? Should I use:

```
static final String MY_STRING = "my very very long string that spans a more than a page.";
```

or

```
static final String MY_STRING = "my very very long string "
    + "that spans more than a page.";
```

Is there any performance hit for one or the other? What if this were not a static final and the declaration were in a method. I know this should be a really easy question for some of you guys.

Comment: Nope. They are concatenated at compile time.

Comment: It's an impossible question because there's no one correct answer. Do whatever you think reads better. Or follow your company's standards.

Comment: @shmosel - There is an answer; he's asking if there is a performance hit for doing it this way.  The answer is no, unless you are also doing it this way with variables. In that case, there is a slight performance hit with concatenating strings. If it becomes a long string, its best to use a `StringBuilder`. But you likely would not notice much of a difference, if any, either way.

Comment: @Zephyr It's not clear whether the question was primarily about best practice or performance. I went with the former.

Comment: The other question didn't come up in my search. Thank you for pointing out that duplicate question. Looks like because my string is a constant making it readable is the right way to go because the compiler will optimize the performance for us. You guys rock, again Thank you!

Comment: @simgineer That's a pretty general rule: The compiler optimizes a lot and usually, you don't have to care. Write readable code using small methods, that's what the compiler (and you colleagues) love most.